# Is there a way to run arbitrary command in MongoVUE

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

I was looking for a way to execute an arbitrary command in MongoVUE: `db.collection.runCommand(..)`, but was not able to find anything.

I am using the latest (at the time of asking) version 1.6.1.0. There is nothing in the context menu as well as in the main menu:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve it? If no, are there any other suitable guis for desktop (not web-based).

P.S. I know how to perform this in mongo-shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into the same limitation with the .distinct() command. It is not currently possible in MongoVUE to do anything aside from .find/.aggregate/.mapreduce. You're best off running commands out of the Mongo Shell.